# HTML Newbie With Nested event.value question

Tags: html

I have an HTML project and I need to nest several operations into one line of code to simplify. I want several fields to be changed based on the selection of another field. Can I "OR" them together within event.value. obviously this isn't working, any suggestions?

```
else if (event.value==("Bunker"||"Coal Creek"||"Fords Prairie"||"Morton"||"Salkum")){this.getField("CCR").value = "N/A";
this.getField("CBN").value = "N/A";
this.getField("HTR").value = "N/A";
this.getField("SWT").value = "N/A";
this.getField("LTS").value = "N/A";
```

Comment: First of all, this is not HTML. Second of all - share full code example for others to be able to test it and help you. And try reading this: [How to ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Now it's not clear what do you want!?

Answer (score 1):

`("Bunker"||"Coal Creek"||"Fords Prairie"||"Morton"||"Salkum")` evaluates as `"Bunker"`, so that is the only value you compare `event.value` to.

If you want to find out if a value matches any in a list, then put the list in an array and use [`yourArray.includes(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

I don't wanna assume but this looks to be written in JS not HTML. JS if statements evaluate things one by one. To make the code work you would need to have it written as:

```
(event.value=="Bunker") || (event.value == "Coal Creek") || etc.
```

There might be a better way to do it where it isn't so tedious that I don't know of.